# Does the Twilio PHP helper library use the deprecated SMS/Messages resource? How to update?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

Twilio recommends that developers switch from using the old `SMS/Messages` API resource to the new `/Messages` one (see the [API documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms), as well as [problems with SMS status when using the old version](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/why-are-my-messages-status-sent)).

I'm using the [twilio-php](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php) helper library, which is Twilio's official recommendation for PHP development. It appears that this library is sending requests to `/2010-04-01/Accounts/{sid}/SMS/Messages/` (e.g, [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Services/Twilio/Rest/SmsMessages.php) and [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/tests/TwilioTest.php)).

Questions:

1. Am I correct in thinking that the library is using the old API resource?
2. Is there an expedient way to update it, or anyplace I can find an updated version?
3. Is there a guide to any changes that might be necessary when switching to the new resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Sure. It is still providing capability for the old resources. Deprecation of a feature in a widely used library is a long process that requires a bit of forward/backward compatibility considerations. The tests still include the old resources to ensure that backwards compatibility still isn't being broken.
2. The new `Messages` resource is [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Services/Twilio/Rest/Messages.php). That is your updated version.
3. Follow the instructions noted in the [`Messages` docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message).

It seems that any line that goes like this

```
$client->account->sms_messages->// ... and so on
```

Should be changed to:

```
$client->account->messages->// ... and so on
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. In particular, I had looked at the Messages docs but missed the link at the bottom with instructions on sending messages.

Comment: To clarify, you can't _just_ change "sms_messages" to "messages". For example, the function for sending a sms changes from `$client->account->sms_messages->create()` to `$client->account->messages->sendMessage()` .